# DataInputStream readInt() works only once

Tags: java, android, sockets, datainputstream

I'm using Java sockets to make two android devices communicating with the same app. The communication protocol is:

```
1. client sends packet size S
2. client sends byte array with size S
```

I'm using `DataOutputStream` and `writeInt()` to write the size as raw value on the stream. The server then reads this value whit `DataInputStream` and `readInt()`.
The problem is that `readInt()` reads the right value only for the first packet. The second time this method returns a random `int`.

Relevant code snippets:

Client side: this method is called on top of a working TCP connection with the server

```
public void write(byte[] packet)
{
    try
    {
        dataOutputStream.writeInt(packet.length);
        dataOutputStream.flush();

        dataOutputStream.write(packet);
        dataOutputStream.flush();        
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "write() failed", e);
    }
}
```

Server side: this is the loop that reads data

```
...

int readBytes = 0;
int packetSize = 0;

while (true) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[NET_BUFF_SIZE];

    try // first it reads the packet size from packet header
    {
        packetSize = dataInputStream.readInt();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "readInt() failed", e);
        return;
    }

    while (readBytes < packetSize) {
        try {
            int readResult = dataInputStream.read(buffer);

            if (readResult != -1) {
                readBytes += readResult;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(ERROR_TAG, "read() failed", e);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, when the client calls `write()` to send the second packet, the server reads a wrong size from the stream.

`DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` are initialized in this way:

```
// Server
inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

// Client
outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Throw away your loop that reads the packet and use readFully().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server side you should re-initialize the `readBytes` variable after the `while(true)` loop:

```
while (true) {
     readBytes = 0;
     ....
}
```

All the best. A debugger would help you spot this problem sooner.

Comment: @Joni's answer should be implemented as well, though, or it may become a suprise bug later.... (the reason it is not a bug now is probably because of the flush() call in the client, but that is not  reliable situation.... if the client were to send two very fast packets, you may have a problem

Answer (score 4):

The server reads as much data as is available. It may read more than what's included in the packet that the client sent, or it may read less. With the loop you seem to handle the case when `read` returns less than what you expect, but you also should handle the case when it reads more than what's included in the packet. Remember that TCP is stream-oriented: even though you call `flush` there's no guarantee that the remote application receives the data in separate calls to `read`.

The `DataInput` interface defines a method called `readFully` that reads exactly as many bytes as you want, no more and no less. This means you can remove the loop, simplifying the code to read a packet to this:

```
packetSize = dataInputStream.readInt();
dataInputStream.readFully(buffer, 0, packetSize);
```